# How to add an icon to a button in GTK3?

Tags: c, button, icons, gtk3

I am using Glade to generate C-based GUI's. I have a GtkButton in my UI and would like to display an icon on it.

In glade there seems to be an option on the General properties of the GtkButton called 'Label with optional image'. However, I can't get this to work.

On the main() I have:

```
button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "start_button");
button = gtk_button_new_from_icon_name ("document-new-symbolic", GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON);
```

In the same folder where i run the binary file, I have a small document-new-symbolic.png. On the [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html) it says that "If the icon name isn’t known, a “broken image” icon will be displayed instead." However, in my case, just the normal button appears without any icon.

What is going on? Why is the icon not displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_file("document-new-symbolic.png");
gtk_button_set_image(button, image);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of doing this with glade? Also, is the icon file a .png or what?

Comment: You can get button widget via `button=GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"button1"));` that defined by glade as button1.

Comment: thanks, but still does not work. I have updated my question. Would you mind having a look at it?

Comment: try to use `gtk_button_set_image`

Comment: should I write gtk_button_set_image(button,"document-new-symbolic.png"); after button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "start_button");?

Comment: `GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_file("xxx");` and 
`gtk_button_set_image(button, image);`